# trigger to prevent modification psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

i made this trigger to prevent data modification in psql

but it prevent  insert data too , how i can resolve this problem ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.Check_Modification()
        RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
    AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
    
        
        RAISE EXCEPTION ' Sorry u can not modifict  the data  ' ; 
        END IF;
    
        RETURN NEW;
    
    END;
    $BODY$;
    
    ALTER FUNCTION public.check_verwachte_bezetting()
        OWNER TO postgres;
    
    
    
    CREATE TRIGGER Check_Modification_trigger
        BEFORE UPDATE
        ON public.table
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE FUNCTION public.Check_Modification();
```

Comment: Not seeing how, unless you created a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that points at this function.

Comment: Your function has a syntax error, and you ALTER a different function than the one you CREATE.  But once those are fixed, it works fine for me.  UPDATE disallowed, INSERT is allowed.

Comment: Just a couple observations. You are not checking anything, you are just preventing **any**  `update` the `public.table`. Since it is good practice to name your processes o reflect a better name would be `prevent_modification`.  Since you are issuing a exception in every case a `statement level`  would be sufficient.  Your trigger **will not** prevent inserts since it only runs on `Update` .

Comment: Use permissions for that, it is simpler and more efficient.